# How can I alter the output from my list and sum?

Tags: python

I am having a problem with the output my code is giving me and I am stumped. The output should look like this:

```py
1,2,3,4 = 10
```

But instead, I am getting this:

```py
[1,2,3,4] = 10
```

Can anyone review my code and tell me why its outputting that?

Here it is:

```py
def sumList(NumList):
    NumList = [int(input('Enter the number: ')) for i in range(4)]
    print(NumList, "=" ,sum(NumList))
sumList(4)
```

Comment: Because you are printing a list of ``1``, ``2``, ``3`` and ``4`` and ``[1,2,3,4]`` is how such a list is printed (actually, it's ``[1, 2, 3, 4]``).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NumList` is a list object, which is denoted by the squared brackets, that's why when you print it shows `[1,2,3,4]`.

If you want to print it like `1,2,3,4 = 10` you will need to treat it first with something like

```
NewList = [str(i) for i in NumList]
NewList = ','.join(NewList)
```

then your final function should be

```
def sumList(NumList):
  NumList = [int(input('Enter the number: ')) for i in range(4)]
  NewList = [str(i) for i in NumList]
  NewList = ','.join(NewList)
  print(NewList, "=" ,sum(NumList))
```

Comment: Just an observation, the parameter `NumList` you are passing to the function is useless, since it is being defined again inside the function. So you can use `sumList(1)` or `sumList(100)` and it will be the same. If you want to pass the quantity of numbers you want to sum you need to make some alterations like `def numList(N)` and `NumList = [int(input('Enter the number: ')) for i in range(N)]`

Comment: You might want to brush up the variable naming. ``NewList`` is very misleading for a *string*.